# Bathroom Vanity wood getting damaged slowly

Tags: moisture, bathroom-fixtures, vanity

Anyway to stop this happening. I always use the fan when taking a shower still the top edge of the vanity wood is opening slowly. Anyway i can stop this and fix it ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all those vanities are made with particle board and will absorb moisture way before your fan can get rid of it. You might be able to slow it down by coating it with an exterior wood glue and then painting it or by using a quality silicone caulk and forcing it in there. Make sure the area it dry before applying anything or you'll trap the moisture.

Comment: Any chance of fixing it ? Or reducing the opening i am renting n wanna try n fix if possible

Comment: You might be able to scrape out some of the expanded particle board and the glue and clamp that corner.... just be very careful not to crack the laminate because that's impossible to hide or patch.

Comment: As a renter, @SP979, you may want to point it out to the landlord and ask him what she'd like to do about it before it gets worse. Maybe send an email with a picture so you've documented that you brought it up, just in case he tries to charge you for repairs when you move out.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it but not really as a renter.   If you glue it it will just happen again or the moisture will damage other areas.   You will need to use some sort of light epoxy filler plus a coating to keep mdf vanities from failing.    This is not a change a renter does to a vanity without landlord approval.    I would for sure take pictures and send to landlord - because when this fails and then you bump into it and it breaks pieces off, well the landlord may say you are at fault.

If the landlord has a maintenance guy he will come out and glue it back and then it will fail in a few months.   He will not spend the time giving the vanity a coating because said coating is not easy to do while looking good, especially on white+mdf.   Sorry to be a downer here.